# Extend Maven artifact search in Intellij

Tags: maven, web-applications, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Is there any way to extend Maven artifact search in Intellij ? I'm not sure how this works in other IDEs. If I search for artifact I have a list of them but it's not complete e.g. if I want to add another dependency such as JAXRS I have to manually navigate to maven repository website, find the artifact id, group id and paste it into the pom.xml. It would be great to search for it within IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a search available inside intellij, but it only works on the artefact/group id. To enable it, IntelliJ needs to index the repositories (which means downloading a big xml and generating and index from it). To do this

- Go to settings
- Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Maven -> Repositories
- Select all the repositories you see, and click on `Update`.
- Wait... as it might take a bit for this to complete as the downloaded file is about 1GB (uncompressed) if my memory serves me right.

That should allow you to search by all group and artefact id (and also retrieve all the versions available); but you won't be able to search by class name or sha1, as you can do in maven central.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I can search by class name though, I'm using intellij 15